# Program exit, functioncall in conditional in sequence diagrams

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

The following code belongs to an object of class called "Console".

```
    if ( problem.success() ) {
                display("Congratulations.  You solved the problem using " +
                        moveCount + " moves.\n");
                System.exit(0);
    }
    display(options);
```

How to show a function call like problem.success() in conditional statement? Should I just assign the result to a temporary variable and then test on that variable?

Also how to show that a program exits if the conditional is true otherwise continues? Should I just make a note?